# Does Mac OSX Support period in username

Tags: macos, osx-lion, osx-server

I can't seem to find any concrete proof of this but I wanted to know whether or not a period is allowed in a mac username (the name that you use to log into the OS).

If it's not allowed, is there any settings somewhere which will enable this feature or is there any workaround to this ?

Comment: It'd be intesting to see the behavior with user names where the part after the `.` is a bundle extension, e.g. `.key` or `.pages`. I expect this will misbehave rather badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Mac OS X is very Unixy, you should probably follow the [answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/73084/what-characters-should-i-use-or-not-use-in-usernames-on-linux) by [steveha](https://serverfault.com/users/19112/steveha):

> My advice to you is to follow the standard recommended [ASCII lowercase letters, numbers, and the hyphen]. You can actually put nearly anything in a user name under *NIX but you may encounter odd problems with library code that makes assumptions.

Comment: We have an LDAP server for our domain login, and we wanted to import all that user information into lion server. The usernames all contain a period in them, so we wanted to know if there is any way that can work. If period isn't supported, then probably we will have to do a lot of manual work........

Comment: @SayemAhmed: You might have already considered this, but Mac OS X does let you authenticate against an LDAP server. Perhaps that would solve both the "period in username" issue and prevent you from having to import a lot of data? I can't say I've ever set this up myself, though.